# MS teams: Get a members list of a channel without asking for permission which requires admin consent?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have tried /groups/{groupID}/members?$count=true & /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/members apis but both of them required permissions that require admin consent so that won't be a feasible solution for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, whenever you tried to add permission it required admin consent to approve the permission .

But i got confused with your API - /groups/{siteId}/members?$count=true , when you tried to call group members you should use - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members?$count=true](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/members?$count=true)

And you should have at least 1 permission - GroupMember.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

Doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I cannot use the above API because it requires permission which requires admin consent. Is there any other API or method to fetch this data? I can use permissions which don't require admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

All APIs which allow listing any group's members require admin consent by default.

Keep in mind that whether user consent is allowed for a permission, for a given app, is up to the customer, and different organizations have different settings.